# Retrieving Messages in Qt from PostThreadMessage

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a small C++ application, where I am linking in another custom C++ library.
From within that library, I am using PostThreadMessage to transmit some status information back to the Qt GUI. However, I am not sure how to intercept those messages. If I use PostMessage instead, I can process the information sent back using winEvent.
Is there a way I can do the same for PostThreadMessage?

Thanks in advance,
SL

Comment: *Never* use PostThreadMessage() to post messages to a thread that creates any windows.  You'll lose the messages when the thread pumps another message loop.  Like the ones that are used to resize a window or display a message box.

Answer (score 0):

The remarks section of the [MSDN PostThreadMessage page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) talks about how to handle these messages. It is the same general process as [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Nick, I actually had seen that, and was reading through it, however I was interested in how to handle them from a Qt perspective. That is, the way i can override the Qt winEvent function to handle messages sent with PostMessage, what would the equivalent method be to capture messages send with PostThreadMessage...